# d3.js with coffeescript - use the timer make strange behavior

Tags: animation, d3.js, timer, attributes, coffeescript

I'm starting with d3.js and I don't understand a strange call function. I'm using coffeescript and here is my code :

it doesn't work :

```
handleTick = () ->
    t += 0.01   
    d3.select('.ball').attr({cx: (width / 2) + 100 * Math.cos(w * t), cy: (height / 2) + 100 * Math.sin(w * t)})    
d3.timer handleTick
```

it work :

```
handleTick = () ->
    t += 0.01   
    console.log d3.select('.ball').attr({cx: (width / 2) + 100 * Math.cos(w * t), cy: (height / 2) + 100 * Math.sin(w * t)})    
d3.timer handleTick
```

Thanks !

Comment: Read: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#d3_timer - how do the results of the two functions differ? Remember that CoffeeScript, unlike JavaScript, automatically returns the value of the last expression even if there is no `return`.

Comment: I tried to add an explicite true return but still not nork

Answer (score 1):

try

```
handleTick = () ->
  t += 0.01   
  d3.select('.ball').attr({cx: (width / 2) + 100 * Math.cos(w * t), cy: (height / 2) + 100 * Math.sin(w * t)})
  return 0
```

as mentioned in the comments, coffeescript always returns the last expression, since `console.log` statements return void, it would make sense that the `d3.select` statement is probably returning something the api isn't expecting.

Comment: Void is a reserved word, the coffee compiler return me a error

Comment: ah, so it does @user2864740. changing my answer to fix that. thanks.